# start a new activity from button click within listview (using simplecursoradapter)

Tags: android, listview, button, simplecursoradapter

I have a listview which I am populating with a custom SimpleCursorAdapter, each row contains a button which, when clicked should open a new activity and pass the ID of the original data object so I can display the related image on screen.

I am having problems implementing the onclick event for the button and I understand you can only use startActivity() within an activity - is this correct?  if so, is there a workaround as my cursoradapter code is in it's own class which extends SimpleCursorAdapter (ie. not in an activity!)

Just one more question if I may? - how can I pass the dataobject ID (ImageID) of the button clicked to the new activity?

Comment: Can you post a bit of relevant code for us to suggest changes on?

Comment: You can pass the activity context to your adapter and then call: context.startActivity(...);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `click listener` over `Button` in `getView()` method in your adapter and use `startActivity` from there.